# Sniffing packets over a wifi network, with or without monitor mode using wireshark

Tags: wireshark, sniffing

So, I am actually confused, there are some guides that say you can't just capture traffic on wireless LAN with promiscuous mode and you need to setup monitor mode, also enter the wifi password to be able to decrypt the data.

But then there are some guides that say as long as the device is on your lan network, you can capture their wifi traffic fine with promiscuous mode over a wireless network.

So which one is it actually?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the "some guides"? As this is already an interpretation instead of a citation, it's hard to explain what they really intended to tell on these tutorials.

Comment: @EsaJokinen

https://lifehacker.com/how-to-tap-your-network-and-see-everything-that-happens-1649292940

https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN

https://ask.wireshark.org/question/10189/why-cant-i-capture-other-devices-packets-on-the-network/